# Is there a special name for a category with all morphisms being morphisms from an initial object?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal C$ be a (small) category whose only non-identity morphisms are morphisms from an initial object.

I guess $\mathcal C$ can be obtained by adjoining an initial object to a *discrete* category.

Is there a special name for this type of category? (I might have called it a "bouquet of morphisms", but this doesn't capture the orientation of the morphisms.)

Comment: For 0, 1, 2, 3 objects these categories have names: 0, 1, $\to$, and span category. Is there a reason you'd expect them to have names in general?

Comment: @MeesdeVries "span" is useful, thank you. I guess "expect" would be too strong, but I thought it is not unreasonable to ask if someone knows of a special name for these — you list names for 0–3, there is one answer mentioning "flat domain" and there is also "multispan" (which turns out to be more general than what I am looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it the "walking cone." See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/walking+structure).

Answer (score 1):

The result is necessarily a partial order. In domain theory, this is called a [flat domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory#Special_types_of_domains).